# How can I save a random JSON object into mongodb, using a nodeJS API?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a bit of raw data that I would like to save, But i don't know what attribute to give it to save it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('data', new Schema({ 
    data: String ???;
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use the data type [Mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) either you can use the [String](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) data type and apply a `JSON.stringify` to the JSON you want to store before to actually insert it into the database.